# How to avoid log files growing too big?

Tags: linux, logging

I have a Linux process generating very big log files.
Those file could grow infinitely if I didn't do anything.
Is there any way to limit a file's size and to make it act like some kind of fifo buffer keeping only a certain amount of data?

I also tried logrotate, but it can't run as soon as the file has reached a given size.
Log files could grow very fast and I don't want to run logrotate on a daily basis.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered a logging server?

Answer (score 4):

You can run run logrotate with a config file specifically for the log file in question and put it into a cron job that runs more often, e.g. every hour or every 15 minutes.

See `man logrotate`.

Comment: I know I can run it more often, but I wouldn't want the file to grow over the fixed size, even if it's just for 1 minute

Comment: @user194998: Make the cron job run every minute

Comment: As I said, even 1 minute would be too much! I only want to keep the last (most recent) 20M of a file, and EXACTLY 20M.

Comment: @user194998 It would be helpful if you mentioned this need in your question.

Comment: Also, *why* do you want this? Is there a good reason for it?

Comment: If that is a hard requirement the do not log into a file but into a memory based ring buffer instead.

Comment: @mschuett: right, or a file-based ring.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   /var/log/filexxx {
       rotate 5
       weekly
       size 100k
   }
```

This will always keep 5 files, rotate either weekly or when it reaches 100k in size (what happens first).