# Capping log file size: FIFO and maxsize

Tags: logging

I am looking for a generic way to hard-cap erratically growing logfiles. The existing answers (linked below) suggest using a polling algo with logrotate, but that approach does not enforce a hard limit (as files can get pretty big even within one minute).

Does anyone know of a solution or implementation? If nothing exists, why not?

Related questions:

- [How to avoid log files growing too big?](https://serverfault.com/questions/546072/how-to-avoid-log-files-growing-too-big)
- [How to rotate log based on an interval unless log exceeds a certain size?](https://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size/474952#474952)

Comment: One essential question is: What do you want with the log entries exceeding your specified maximum log files?

Comment: I would like to discard them (FIFO), so only have the last x lines or MB of log entries.